# JS "as soon as" condition

Tags: javascript

I've got a small problem (kind of a problem with curiosity actually). Is it possible to create some condition when if the condition is satisfied, the appropriate code is executed? Without use of setInterval and setTimeout of course. Or callback? Maybe AJAX?

```
var x;
if (x != "undefined") {
    //code to be executed
}

setTimeout(function() { x = 3.14; }, 5000);

//after those let's say 5 seconds (the time is random) x becomes defined and the code above is executed
```

Thanks!

Comment: look into promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: AJAX is used to get data from the remote server, why you can't use  `seetTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with wrapping `x` inside an object, you can try using setter pattern:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'x', { set: function(xval) { /* do stuff; */ } });

// some time later in the code ...

obj.x = somevalue

// do stuff will fire
```

Or, in the object initializer:

```
var obj = { 
    set x(xval) {
        // do stuff;
    }
}

// some time later in the code...

obj.x = somevalue

// do stuff will fire
```

Note that the only (but optional) value we can explicitly pass to the callback is the value we set the bound property to (the value of `x`). (Of course, you can reference anything that `obj`'s scope can see).

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 0):

when a function depends on another one, I just do a simple callback.

```
var x;
function check_and_wait(callback) {
   if (x != undefined) {
      callback();
    }
}

check_and_wait(function() {
    //code goes here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

A possible solution using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
var x;

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        x = 3.15;
        resolve();
    },3000)
});

promise.then(function(){
   console.log("code to be executed")
   console.log(x)
});
```

Comment: OP mentioned _without use of setInterval and setTimeout_. And why to use promises in this case? You call callback anyway.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this answer. Sure, he used `setTimeout` but his solution is about promises. Promises aren't inherently dependent on `setTimeout`. Even if there was no `setTimeout` this code would still work.

Comment: yea.... not sure why people are downvoting this. Promises are **the** solution to his problem, they incorperate with any delayed code execution

Comment: @Isaac because OP specifically requested an answer that does not invoke `setTimeout`. Update your answer to not use `setTimeout` and you may get more upvotes.